# Is there any plugin for zsh or bash that does heuristic filename completion?

Tags: bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Such as if

```
$ ls
program_v1.21.rb
program_v2.01.rb
program_v2.01_final.rb
```

so when I

```
$ echo progv2fin[TAB]
```

it completes to

```
$ echo program_v2.01_final.rb
```

Sure there must be something, but I haven't seen it.

Comment: Don't cross posting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019711/is-there-any-plugin-for-zsh-or-bash-that-does-heuristic-filename-completion

Comment: Sorry, I was in the process of deleting that other post because it's not the best site to post it.

Comment: If you don't mind adding `_`, zsh can complete `p_v2_f` to `program_v2.01_final.rb`.

Comment: With zsh completion system, `echo fi<TAB>` will give what you want.

Comment: thanks, but it's more in a general case. I'm used to do it that way, with incremental pro[tab]_[tab]2[tab]_[tab] or just fi[tab], if a single match will do, but I guess that if sublime text and most search engines can, there must be a way to do this in zsh.

Comment: Thanks @muru. Almost what I expected. But I guess it still can be done.

Comment: However it looks that you are looking for completion in the same spirit as `ido-mode` in `emacs`. I don't think it is achievable in `zsh`, at least not in simple way. The short term workaround is to increase the number of errors that completion system accepts: look for the `max-errors` completion style in zsh manual.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`, if you're using the completion system, you can do:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'r:|?=**'
```

Which seems to work. I won't pretend I understand fully how that works, you can read:

```
info -f zsh --index-search=matcher-list
```

And also follow the link there to:

```
info zsh 'Completion Matching Control'
```

for details.